# where to add xslt file in ektron

Tags: xml, xslt, ektron

i am working on Ektron[8.60] and a beginner in it, i need to add a smart form with xslt rendering, i have made a smart form under

```
settings> configuration> smart form configurations.
```

Now i clicked on smart form and from above toolbar clicked on edit, here i want to give the path of xslt file , but i don't know what to write here. I tried some path and it says error.

The other thing i want to know that why there are 3 radio buttons like xslt 1, xslt 2 and xslt 3 ? One xslt file is not sufficient ?

Any help or useful link from someone.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The default path for XSLTs is in `/XmlFiles/`, so if you type in `widget.xslt` in the any of the `XSLT #` text boxes, it will use `/XmlFiles/widget.xslt` to render those content blocks.  The cool thing about doing this is that you can just plop a content block server control on the page, and if you tell it to load a content block based on your smartform, it will automatically run your XSLT.

**UPDATE:**
You can use a different path by prefixing your path with "../" -- it's a little messy, but Ektron ends up looking at a path similar to:  `/XmlFiles/../xsl/widget.xslt`.  That has worked for me in the past, but like i said it's a little messy.  If that is causing you troubles, try copying the file into `/XmlFiles/` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: thanks for answer, you are right, actually i wrote "../workarea/xslt/filename.xslt" in my path and is says verification succedded but when i run the page using content block it doesn't show any content, may be the reason is that it adds the prefix "/xmlfiles/.." with the path. what should i do for removing the prefix ?

Answer (score 0):

(3 years later....) The simplest way is to create a folder named xmlfiles and save the XSLT file there.  However, if you need to use a different path, you can change the default path in the web.config file.

Change

```
<add key="ek_xmlPath" value="XmlFiles" />
```

To

```
<add key="ek_xmlPath" value="/" />
```

This will allow you to put the XSLT file in the Library and use the uploaded files path.  In order to upload XSLTs to the Library you must first make it accept that file type.

First, create a whitelist file ie. myWhiteList.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<whitelist>
    <xslt>mySuperSpecialXslt.xslt</xslt>
</whitelist>
```

Then add that whitelist file to ek_smartFormWhitelistConfiguration in the web.config :

```
<add key="ek_smartFormWhitelistConfiguration" value=" myWhiteList.xml" />
```

Next, add it to the acceptable file extensions in the web.config for

```
ek_DMSFileTypeWhiteList
ek_LibFileTypeWhiteList
```

Next, add the new file extention to the Library.  In the CMS, go to the Library tab / View Properties button / edit.  Add the file extension(s), update.  Now you can add the file to the Library and you don't need access to the server to make changes.